# Angular5 filter not working with datatable

Tags: angular, filter

We have some data in angular datatable. I just want to filter those data.
suppose we have a data like India, when I am typing like ind it is displaying the result.
when I typed indw then it is not displaying the result that is fine but When I removed char w then it should display the result.
Please suggest.

```
resultAPI: any;
tempResult: any;
  
ngOnInit() {
    this.getResult();
  }

 public getResult(): void {
    this.resultService.getresultAPI(this.applicationDetail.applicationId).subscribe(response => {
      this.resultAPI = response.payload;
      // cache data for filter purposes.
      this.tempResult = this.resultAPI;
    });
  }
  
  
public filterByName(event): void {
    const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const initialResult = this.tempResult.list;
    const filteredResults = initialResult.filter(function (resultModel) {
      let apiName = resultModel.apiInfo.name;
      apiName = decodeURI(apiName);
      return apiName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1 || !value;
    });
    this.resultAPI.list = filteredResults;
  } 
  
 Html:
  <input matinput *ngIf="resultAPI && resultAPI.count != 0" type='text' class="input-filter" placeholder='Filter by...' (keyup)='filterByName($event)' />
```

Comment: your `tempResult` and `resultApi` point to the same array in memory as you are doing this: `this.tempResult = this.resultAPI;` so whatever happens in either array happens to the other. So you basically keep filtering the same array and therefore loosing items.

Comment: I am applying the filter on initialResult which I am getting from this.tempResult.list. I have never changed or update  the tempResult. Please provide the possible fix.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you have how many arrays, they all point to same array. So when you are doing `const initialResult = this.tempResult.list`, now all **three** variables point to the same array, so what happens in one, happens to all. Read about JavaScript object mutability :)

Comment: For example this: https://www.codementor.io/@manik488/mutability-vs-immutability-in-javascript-1g9hwoeddd